# why is min-height not increasing to accommodate increasing content

Tags: html, css

I thought setting the `min-height` property will expand if necessary to accommodate its contents, but I was shocked to realized that it is not displaying the content at all, especially when I re-size. Some contents is completely loss from display. This code below is not the exact code thought, but this is the closest to my problem I can get.

```
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="box"> Box One</div>
       <div class="box"> Box two</div>
       <div class="box"> Box three</div>
       <div class="box"> Box four</div>
       <div class="box"> Box five</div>
       <div class="box"> Box six</div>
   </div>

    <style>
        .parent {
               min-height: 300px;
               width: 100%; 
               background-color: blue;
           }
         .box {
               width: 50%;
               height: 50px;
               color white;
           }
    </style>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Its accomodating new content. See this https://jsfiddle.net/bro49tg7/

Comment: Looks like your `min-height` is working as expected... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not really sure anymore, but it is different with the real code i was writing.

Comment: works fine and one syntax error in .box class.. (color white;)

Comment: Can you post the code or create a fiddle for the code that is not working?

Comment: `min-height` has nothing to do with boxes expanding to accommodate their content, which is the normal behavior. It has to do with them not shrinking too much. Or are you saying that you somehow want the children to expand to fill `min-height`? That's not how it works. To accomplish something like that, look at flexbox.

Comment: @pedroyanky : check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:** You can see the problem when the content inside the .box increase and the size of the browser is decreased to mobile version. Then you can see the real problem, that the content is getting out of the blue box.

***You can see the problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/bro49tg7/3/ resize the width of the output to smaller screen.***

To Solve this problem

Change your css code to this:

```
.box{
width: 50%;
min-height: 50px; /* changed this */
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This accomplishes what?

Comment: @torazaburo , it will make the div contain all the text and doesn't go out of the div , which was the issue in first place.

Comment: in my case though the contents has no fixed heights, i just wanted it to assume the height of its contents. it was fine at first, but on resize, it was pushed out of the parent content.  I didn't give it a height, cos i wasn't sure of the content size.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly as Hunzaboy says, you need a min-height on each box for this to work. Take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6zpek8m6/

```
.parent {
  min-height: 300px;
}
.box {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```